# Use = operator instead of like in Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a simple filter string in one of my reports which is currently filtering using like operator.

```
strWhereClause = strWhereClause + strConnector + "'" + 
Request.Form["ddlServiceCenter"] + "' In 
CStr[{TBL_Warehouse_Master.WRHM_Service_Center_ID}]";
```

It is a number that ranges from 1 to 25. When I search for 2, it includes result from 2, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 and 25. How do I make sure that it matches only the exact value.

Edit:

I tried replacing `In` with `=`, but that returns no data.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to tag this VB.NET? Doesn't seem C# syntax to me. Anyways, you need to split the result and then check for equality.

Comment: It is part of C# code that creates the selection formula for Crystal reports. Edited the question to include full line to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way around. Obviously, I will still like to know the "exact value" equivalent of `In` operator.

For the time being, below formula worked.

```
strWhereClause = strWhereClause + strConnector + " 
{TBL_Warehouse_Master.WRHM_Service_Center_ID} = " + 
Request.Form["ddlServiceCenter"];
```